# Add Google Analytics events to Navigation Items

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a loop that iterates through list items in a nav, then takes the title attribute from each anchor tag so I can put it into the line of code for analytics where it says title.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function analytics(e) {
    var titles = $('#trending-nav li.cms a').attr("title");
    ga('atealium.send', 'event', 'Navigation', "Trending", titles);
};

var trends = $("#trending-nav li a");
for (var i = 0; i < trends.length; i++) {
    EventUtil.addHandler(trends[i], 'click', analytics);
}
});
```

I'm having trouble finding the correct code to use, here's the basic list I'm using. I'm not sure where to put the code, or the correct format to pull the titles of each item in the nav.

```
<nav class="clearfix inner" id="tren">
<ul>
    <li><a class="tren">TREN</a></li>
<li class="cms ">

        <a href="/age" title="Agency A-Z">Agency A-Z</a>
</li>
<li class="cms ">

        <a href="/brand/brand-a-z" title="BRAND A-Z">BRAND A-Z</a>
</li>
<li class="cms ">

        <a href="/christmas/christmas-ads" title="CHRISTMAS ADS">CHRISTMAS ADS</a>
</li>
<li class="cms ">

        <a href="/johnlewis" title="JOHN LEWIS">JOHN LEWIS</a>
</li>
<li class="cms ">

        <a href="/hav" title="HAV">HAV</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle all of this using jQuery.

Instead of using `EventUtil.addHandler` and because you're already using jQuery, just take advantage of jQuery's click event listener. In this example, I selected all anchors within the `#tren` nav block, then you can call `ga` and pass the title using `$(this).attr('title')`. If you're not familiar with the use of `$(this)`, check out jQuery's documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#tren a").on('click', function () {
    ga('atealium.send', 'event', 'Navigation', "Trending", $(this).attr("title")); 
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Blexy